# Translate mouse click positon to 3D in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm learning Three.js by doing sphere panorama in Three.js (http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html). I need to place a marker into panorama when I click. However, I have no idea to translate 2D position's mouse click to 3D world. I tried ray picking, but it didn't work(the intersets variable was always returned []).

And this is my code:
//I create sphere panorama:

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 60, 40 );
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( -1, 1, 1 ) );var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/2294472375_24a3b8ef46_o.jpg' )
                } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );
```

//I catched event mouse down:

```
 mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
 mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
 var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5);
 projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
 var ray = new THREE.Ray(camera.position, vector.subSelf(camera.position).normalize());
 var intersects = ray.intersectObject(mesh);
     if (intersects.length > 0) {
       //code to add marker
     } else {
            //....
     }
```

Please give me way to solve this problem.
Thanks all.

Comment: this is a good example for ray picking http://soledadpenades.com/articles/three-js-tutorials/object-picking/

Comment: thanks gaitat, but it didn't work as i said above. The thing I want is get 3D position on sphere panorama and give a marker.

Comment: Please upgrade to three.js r.67.

Comment: this is an example from mrdoob, and its version is 67

Comment: Please upgrade YOUR code to r.67-compatible. :-)